# How add environment variables to connect Mongod add-on?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployment, add-on

I will deploy my Node js app to clever-cloud and have a problem with connect to MongoD. I need set environment variables in my code, like 
`process.env['MONGODB_ADDON_HOST']` for the host, `process.env['MONGODB_ADDON_USER']` for the user, etc. Where and how i can do this to connect MongoD add-on.

there my server.js file

```
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var mongoose       = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var ObjectId       = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
// configuration ===========================================

// config files
var db = require('./config/db');

mongoose.connect(db.url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error:", err); 
    } else {
        console.log("Connected correctly to database", db.url);
    }
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3050;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 


require('./app/routes')(app);
// start app ===============================================
app.listen(port);   
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
module.exports = app;
```

And db.js

```
module.exports = {
    url : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/PortfolioDB'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This package may be useful for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-env-file

To use that, you need to install this module in server and client sides, and have .end in both sides for defining their environment variables.